# How to search for items in a list in python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, variables, if-statement

Basically I have two lists of items, and I want to check if an item from the second list is in the first list. Then if that item is in the first list, I want to assign a value to a variable, if it is not in that list, I want to assign a different value to the same variable. (As below)
Can this be done?

```
list1 = ['dog','cat','mouse']

list2 = ['dog','tutle','bird']

if list2 in list1:
    square = 77
else:
    square = 55

print(square)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [set operations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset):

```
if not set(list1).isdisjoint(list2):
```

Two sets are disjoint if they have no elements in common.

Or use the [`any()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) with a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions) to test each value from `list2` in turn:

```
if any(value in list1 for value in list2):
    square = 77
else:
    square = 55
```

or even:

```
square = 77 if any(value in list1 for value in list2) else 55
```

The `value in list1` test would be a lot more efficient if `list1` was a set however.

Answer (score -1):

To answer the question you asked:

```
list1 = ['dog','cat','mouse']
list2 = ['dog','tutle','bird']
for elem in list2:
    if elem in list1:
        square = 77
    else:
        square = 55
    print(elem, "square=", square)
```

But searching a list takes a lot of time. You can get some speedups with a set:

```
set1 = set(list1)
for elem in list2:
    if elem in set1:
        square = 77
    else:
        square = 55
    print(elem, "square=", square)
```

Note that the above code searches list1 for every value in list2. If you want to see if any value in list2 exists in list1, then this should do it:

```
set1 = set(list1)
set2 = set(list2)
if set1.intersection(set2):
    square = 77
else:
    square = 55
```

Comment: You are setting `square = 55` for *every element in `list2` that is not in `list1`*. The value of `square` is determined by the last value in `list2` this way, the other elements don't matter.

Comment: Also, don't build sets that you then discard again. You built 3 such sets; `set2` and the intersection result are both entirely redundant. `set(list1).isdisjoint(list2)` gives you the inverse; `True` if there is no intersection, and *no new set is built*.